Xilium.CefGlue Handle/Override Ctrl+W keypress in Chromium Embedded Framework cefclient.exe, in C# WPF Application
I am working on C# WPF Application which is using Xilium CefGlue Chromium Embedded Framework.
Overview: Inside the embedded browser when I click on Ctrl+F, it opens a Chromium inbuilt Find dialog.
Till here everything is fine.
The problem is when the cursor is inside the Find Dialog box like below and then

when I press Ctrl+W, it closes the window

when I press Ctrl+N, it opens a new Chromium Browser Instance



I tried following approaches:
Approach 1: Try capturing the key events in class CustomKeyboardHandler, but whatever I press/type inside the chromium Find Dialog box, following function doesn't capture keyboard events(till the cursor is active in Chromium Inbuilt find dialog.
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Xilium.CefGlue;

public class CustomKeyboardHandler : CefKeyboardHandler
{
    protected override bool OnPreKeyEvent(CefBrowser browser, CefKeyEvent keyEvent, IntPtr osEvent, out bool isKeyboardShortcut)
    {
        isKeyboardShortcut = false;

        if (keyEvent.Type == CefKeyEventType.KeyUp)
        {
            // Handle the key press event
            HandleKeyPress(keyEvent);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void HandleKeyPress(CefKeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        // Check the pressed key and perform desired actions
        if (keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode == (int)Keys.F1)
        {
            // Handle the F1 key press
            Console.WriteLine("F1 key pressed!");
        }
        else if (keyEvent.WindowsKeyCode == (int)Keys.F2)
        {
            // Handle the F2 key press
            Console.WriteLine("F2 key pressed!");
        }
        // Add more key checks as needed
    }
}

Approach 2: Following approach disables the key, but it disables the key Ctrl+W, Ctrl+N in WPF Application, along with in the entire Windows 10.
I just want to disable Ctrl+W, Ctrl+N inside WPF C# Application only.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace Mm.Wpf.GlobalHotKeys
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        private const uint MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
        private const uint MOD_FN = 0x0100;

        private readonly Dictionary<int, (uint, uint)> _hotkeys = new Dictionary<int, (uint, uint)>
        {
            { 1, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x73) }, // Ctrl+F4
            { 2, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x4A) }, // Ctrl+J
            { 3, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x4F) }, // Ctrl+O
            { 4, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x53) }, // Ctrl+S
            { 5, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x4E) }, // Ctrl+N
            { 6, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x48) }, // Ctrl+H
            { 7, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x54) }, // Ctrl+T
            { 8, (MOD_CONTROL, 0x57) }, // Ctrl+W
            { 9, (MOD_FN, 0x72) },      // Fn+F3
            { 10, (MOD_FN, 0x76) },     // Fn+F7
            { 11, (MOD_FN, 0x7A) }      // Fn+F11
        };

        private IntPtr _windowHandle;
        private HwndSource _source;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            _windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(_windowHandle);
            _source.AddHook(HwndHook);

            foreach (var hotkey in _hotkeys)
            {
                RegisterHotKey(_windowHandle, hotkey.Key, hotkey.Value.Item1, hotkey.Value.Item2);
            }
        }

        private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_HOTKEY:
                    int hotkeyId = wParam.ToInt32();
                    if (_hotkeys.ContainsKey(hotkeyId))
                    {
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            _source.RemoveHook(HwndHook);

            foreach (var hotkey in _hotkeys)
            {
                UnregisterHotKey(_windowHandle, hotkey.Key);
            }

            base.OnClosed(e);
        }
    }
}

Approach 3: Used following logic to handle key press events in the WPF embedded CEF browser window, but it doesn't worked out.
    this = MainWindow;// MainWindow is a type of System.Windows.Window
    this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    this.KeyUp += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    this.PreviewKeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    this.PreviewKeyUp += MainWindow_KeyDown;
}
 
private static void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Main Window Key Event");
    if (e.Key == Key.W && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        // Handle Ctrl+W case
        e.Handled = true;  // Prevent further processing of this key
    }
}

